# How to avoid BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field error

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, autowired

I have the following spring test configuration with different profiles:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan (value = {"uk.co.test.ws" })
public class SpringTestConfig
{


    @Profile( "local")
    @PropertySource( "classpath:/config/local/settings.properties" )
    public static class SpringTestConfigLocal
    {
        @Autowired
        private Environment environment ;  

        @Bean(name= "baseUrl" )
        public String setBaseUrl()
        {
            return environment .getRequiredProperty("baseurl.protocol" )+"://" +environment .getRequiredProperty( "baseurl.host");             
        }
    }
```

and then created a base class that takes in the base url

```
> @RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. class) @ContextConfiguration
> (classes = { SpringTestConfig. class }) public class BaseWsTest {
>     @Autowired
>     String baseUrl;
```

which then gets extended to other test classes like below:

```
public class SampleFTest extends BaseWsTest
{
    @Test
    public void hello() throws FileNotFoundException, Exception
    {
        System. out .println("base url: " + baseUrl );
```

When run using normal maven clean install the tests works but if I was to run it by right-clicking the method it gets a

```
Error creating bean with name 'uk.co.test.ws.service.base.SampleFTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

Comment: "By right-clicking" i guess in some IDE? If so, you should check configuration for this task in you IDE.

Comment: Yes on eclipse, sorry I forgot to mention. Right click run "JUnit Test". What configuration should it have? I have added -Dspring.profile.active=local in vm arguments and it still does not work..

Comment: Do you have only message "Injection of autowired dependencies failed;" or you can see full stacktrace? Usually spring shows also reason of fail. "Can't find bean" or some thing like this. Based on this message you can understand what you need to add in your configuration for JUnit task.

Comment: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.lang.String uk.co.gamma.gnp.ws.service.base.GnpWsTest.baseUrl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Those are the complete exception. I forgot how to make it so the stacktrace would look clearer in stackoverflow comment sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to choose the profile in your `SampleFTest` class, you should add this line:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "local")
```

In this way the `SpringTestConfigLocal` will be initialized and the `baseUrl` bean available

**EDIT**: I would add a property in a `.properties` file so I could use a variable myprofile:

`@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "${myprofile}")`

And eventually, if you don't want to change the value from time to time, I would apply some logic in order to load one property file or another.

**EDIT 2**: I'm sorry but this doesn't work because the file is loaded after the assigment of the annotation EL value, but you can add this:

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

to the property file and this will do the same as putting the annotation `@IntegrationTest("local")`. This is the code I tried:

```
@TestPropertySource(value="classpath:/config/test.properties")//, properties={"myaddress=cane", "myprofile=local"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("${myaddress}")
//@ContextConfiguration
//@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "${myprofile}")
public class BasicJUnitTest{

    protected Logger logger;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    
    @Value("${myaddress}" )
    String myval;
    
    
    public BasicJUnitTest(){
        this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }
        
    @Test
    public void test(){
        logger.info("hola"+myval+ " " + env.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Oh wow that worked, thank you. Is there a way to make it so it uses the profile in pom.xml? I would like it so I can compile the test with certain profile , so I wont have to keep changing that line.

Comment: I don't know how to use a variable from the pom.xml, but I would use a property file as I wrote in the edit

Comment: Thank you. I have tried adding it in my settings.properties file  but it's not being picked up

Comment: Did you add `@TestPropertySource("/your_properties.properties")` to your test?

Comment: Ive put it right above the @ActiveProfiles annotation and unfortunately it still does not work. Could you give examples please?

Comment: Not really. Sorry maybe its just me being silly but I am not sure I understand what `@IntegrationTest("${myaddress}")` is for

Comment: Don't worry it's not useful, it's necessary to specify the address where spring boot has to bind. If it was solved would you mark the question as solved?